# How to keep mongoose connection alive

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```js
const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(mongoURI);

    console.log("Database Connected");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
module.exports = connectDB;
```

in server.js

`connectDB();`

is there a way to keep this alive. It gets quite annoying to wait for it to connect on every file change.

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with Mongoose, but you should probably save the actual connection to a variable instead of making the variable a function, which connects to the database. like shown:

```
   let db;
   async function connect() {
        try {
            db = await mongoose.connect(mongoURI);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            process.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

I haven't tested this, but the idea should be similar.
Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Wouldn’t make any difference. When a change is made to any of the files in the module, the code would re-run and wait for connection to resolve every time.